# Average of selected values in option tags

Tags: php

Goodday. Im trying to develop a evaluation program which helps the student to evaluate their enrolled subject. And im having a hard time in getting the total average of evaluated subjects. Please help.

**This is my starting code**

```
  <select name="answer[]">
  <option value=''>-</option>
  <option value='5'>5 - Excelent</option>
  <option value='4'>4 - Very Good</option>
  <option value='3'>3 - Good</option>
  <option value='2'>2 - Fair</option>
  <option value='1'>1 - Poor</option>
  </select>
```

please help.

Comment: This code seems incomplete and it'll be hard to help you with just this. Do you have any server side logic that you could show us?

Comment: So each student is evaluating multiple subjects on the same page and everything is sent in one request (POST or GET, from one form)? And you just want the average of how THAT student evaluated each subject?

Comment: No @Michael, just 1 subject and i want to get average of his answer to all the questions.

Comment: All part of the same form, on one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your form is something like this:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <select name='answers[]'>
        <option value=''>-</option>
        <option value='5'>5 - Excellent</option>
        ...
    </select>

    <select name='answers[]'>
        <option value=''>-</option>
        <option value='5'>5 - Excellent</option>
        ...
    </select>

    <select name='answers[]'>
        <option value=''>-</option>
        <option value='5'>5 - Excellent</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

Then the following would compute the average of all of the answers

```
function myaveragefunction($values) {
    $sum = 0;
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if ($value == '') {
            continue; 
        }

        $sum += $value;
        $count++;
    }

    if ($count > 0) {
        return $sum / $count;
    }

    return 0;
}

$average = myaveragefunction($_POST['answers']);
```

Keep in mind though, you will need a database (whether it be files or a MySQL-like database) to keep the answers for your viewing (assuming that is the purpose of this.

Comment: This is a big help dude. Thank you for your kindness and consideration.  Godbless you:)